# IBM Datastage assumes a column is WVARCHAR while it's date

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I'm doing an ETL for a job. For the data source stage, I input custom select statement. In the output tab of data source stage, I defined the INCEPTION column data type is Timestamp. The right data type for INCEPTION is date. I check it via DBEAVER. But somehow the `IBM Datastage` assumes that it is `WVARCHAR`. It says `ODBC_Connector_0: Schema reconciliation detected a type mismatch for field INCEPTION. When moving data from field type WVARCHAR(min=0,max=10) into DATETIME(fraction=6), data corruption can occur (CC_DBSchemaRules::reportTypeMismatch, file CC_DBSchemaRules.cpp, line 1,838)`. I don't know why it is, since from the database shows that INCEPTION is definitely a Date column. I don't know how to fix this since I don't think I'm making mistake. What did I do wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know the exact solution to fix this but converting the column into `datetime` does the trick, at least the system will shut up about the error

Comment: How did you check the data type with DBeaver? Make sure to select the database catalog to get the correct data type of the column. The exact query depends on your database system.

Answer (score 0):

Where did DataStage get its table definition?  DataStage is a computer program; it can't "decide" anything.  If you import the table definition from the source, what data type is INCEPTION ?  If it is either Date or Timestamp, load that table definition into your DataStage job.  Otherwise explicitly convert the string using StringToTimestamp() function in a Transformer stage.